# Docker compose stops printing standard out and then unexpectedly quits

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running two binary services (each written in C++) through docker-compose 1.22.0. There's nothing particularly special about the `docker-compose.yml`. Both services use host networking, have `init: true`, use `user: "0"`, and have large volumes on the host container, but otherwise their commands are pretty much just running binary files. (unfortunately, for software licensing reasons, I cannot give much more information, but I know of nothing else relevant)

What's happening is that occasionally and inconsistently (I'd say at least 75% of the time, it works fine), both services will stop printing to the console after perplexingly outputting the following:

```
first_service_1    | second_service_1   |
```

`first_service_1` is colored differently than `second_service_1`, and they look identical to the other log lines except without a newline between them.

After that, nothing gets printed. The services (which expose services on ports) will still respond to requests, but they won't print what they're supposed to/what they normally print.

After some time (it's unclear how much exactly), `first_service` will quit like so:

```
my-dockerfiles_first_service_1 exited with code 1
```

Assuming docker-compose isn't causing the exit (which I'm unsure of because it seems to mostly crash only when it fails to print), I'd be able to debug this more easily. I know of no reason printing should ever fail or it should ever print a log line without a newline at the end.

Can anyone advise me on why docker compose might print that odd line or stop printing entirely?

The host environment is Ubuntu 16.04 on an aarch64 NVidia TX-2 running L4T 28.2. docker-compose was installed recently (within the last couple of weeks) through pip. Docker is on version 18.06.0-ce.

Comment: Why not try to increment ```COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT```,  for instance ```COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=1000 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml .......```

Comment: @juliansalas I don't know how that relates to my question. I don't think I have any indication that the docker daemon is hanging.